# Approximability of the genus problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, approximation-hardness, topological-graph-theory

What is currently known about the approximability of the genus problem? A preliminary search tells me that a constant factor approximation is trivial for sufficiently dense graphs, and an $n^\epsilon$-approximation algorithm has been ruled out. Is this information up-to-date, or are there better bounds known?

Answer (score 8):

The best published results all appear in a [1997 paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019097002032) by Jianer Chen, Saroja P. Kanchi, and Arkady Kanevsky.

- For any fixed $\varepsilon>0$, computing the genus of a graph with *additive* error $O(n^\varepsilon)$ is NP-hard.
- There is a trivial linear-time algorithm to embed any $n$-vertex graph of (unknown) genus $g$ on an orientable surface of genus $\max\{4g, g+4n\}$: Assign an *arbitrary* cyclic order to the edges leaving each vertex (keeping loops and parallel edges together).  In other words, when the genus is large, *every* embedding is a good approximation of the *best* embedding.
- There is a polynomial-time $O(\sqrt{n})$-approximation algorithm for bounded-degree graphs.

It is an open question whether there is an efficient constant-factor approximation algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand how it follows from [Chen, Kanchi, Kanevsky '97] that computing the genus with the *multiplicative* approximation of $O(n^{\varepsilon})$ is NP-hard. E.g. computing the MAX CUT with an additive approximation $O(n^{\varepsilon})$ is also NP-hard, but the algorithm of Goemans and Williamson gives 0.878... approximation.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I've updated my answer in light of yours.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to add to JɛﬀE's comprehensive answer that to the best of my knowledge there are no lower bounds on the approximation factor for this problem. As far as we know, there can be an approximation algorithm that **always** gives a constant factor approximation (even if the genus is very small).

The paper Chen, Kanchi, and Kanevsky [CKK '97] only says that computing the genus with additive error $O(n^{1-\varepsilon})$ is NP-hard. Here is a very informal outline of their argument. It will be clear that this argument cannot be used to prove a lower bound on the approximation factor. Consider a graph $G$ such that it is NP-hard to determine whether $\mathrm{genus}(G) \leq g^*$ or $\mathrm{genus}(G) \geq g^*+1$ (for some $g^*$); such a graph exists since the problem is NP-hard. Let $n$ be the number of vertices in $G$. Let $k$ be a large constant. Take $N = n^k$ disjoint copies of the graph $G$ and consider their union. Then in the obtained graph $G'$, it is NP-hard to determine whether $\mathrm{genus}(G') \leq N g^*$ or $\mathrm{genus}(G') \geq N(g^*+1)$. That is, it is NP-hard to compute $\mathrm{genus}(G')$ with additive error $N = (Nn)^{k/{k+1}} = |V(G')|^{k/{k+1}} = |V(G')|^{1-\varepsilon}$, where $\varepsilon = 1/(k+1)$. This construction does not give us any lower bound on the approximation factor; the ratio of $N(g^*+1)$ to $Ng^*$ equals the ratio of $g^*+1$ to $g^*$.